# Authentication with ADFS 2.0

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, adfs2.0, adfs

I'm trying to debug my ADFS installation. I ran into this blogpost: http://www.dagint.com/2011/10/how-to-test-if-adfs-is-functioning/ and I've discovered that I can successfully authenticate on the machine where ADFS is installed (i.e. if I open up https:///adfs/ls/IdpInitiatedSignon.aspx  on the local machine, everything works fine. However, if I open the same URL from another machine, I'm prompted with the familiar authentication windows supplied by the browser, but even though I type in the correct user name and password, I get prompted with the same window again and again.

Althought this may be strictly non-programming related, one might say that this IS related to the authentication of Web API's, which is what I want to achieve eventually.

Any idea whatsoever what could be the cause of this?

Regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 1):

This rings a bell!

[IdpInitiatedSignon.aspx Page Will not Authenticate](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/77455866-b7ce-41ac-98f3-cb1f68ff52d8/idpinitiatedsignonaspx-page-will-not-authenticate).

Could it be the DNS problem mentioned there?

Comment: Sounds quite likely. Will investigate further.